# My kafka consumer does not consume messages from offset 0 as expected

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**kafka version: 5.5.3-ccs**

Good morning,
I noticed a behavior with my kafka consumer written in java and I hope anyone could help me with this.

My consumer looks like this:

```
while (true){
    long pollInterval = 50; //milliseconds
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = this.consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(pollInterval));
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> rec: records){
        logger.debug(String.format("processing record(topic=%s, partition=%s, offset=%s, key=%s)", rec.topic(), rec.partition(), rec.offset(), rec.key()));
    }
}
```

I recreate my topics before any tests because our test chain will create new topics for each of them.

The commands I'm using to recreate my topics are

```
./kafka-topics --bootstrap-server host:port --topic ${TOPIC} --delete
./kafka-topics --bootstrap-server host:port --topic ${TOPIC} --create --replication-factor 2 --partitions 2
```

After my test, I know the number of messages that were posted but my log file shows less messages were consumed.

I check if my consumer-group was lagging for this topic but it wasn't the case

```
GROUP           TOPIC                                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
test-group      topic                                          0          19464           19464           0
test-group      topic                                          1          19275           19275           0
```

Then looking in details at my log file I noticed the first message consumed for both partitions didn't start from offset 0 (respectively offset 79 for partition 0 / offset 70 for partition 1)

```
2021-09-13 15:15:16,780[Thread-0][MyKafkaConsumer][getMessage]-DEBUG- processing record(topic=topic, partition=1, offset=70, key=6154475)
2021-09-13 15:15:17,046[Thread-0][MyKafkaConsumer][getMessage]-DEBUG- processing record(topic=topic, partition=0, offset=79, key=6154476)
```

My understanding is if I recreate my topics, it's like resetting offset and in that case I'll consume all messages posted in this topic from the beginning. Here I basically miss 149 messages.

Anyone could explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at the offset after resetting the topic?

Comment: Hello Gael, I'm checking the offset after recreating myt topic with the command `./kafka-run-class kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list host:port --time -1 --topic ${TOPIC}` and it returns 0 for both partitions